# How can I use RETURNING to UPDATE an id in a temp table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-returning

I am importing a file from an outside source. I've already gotten the data into a temp table similar to below. I need to get the person_id from the t_person table into my temp table so that I can do several more operations with it.
I have a workaround by using a key on the temp table that also gets inserted into t_person, but it's messy and it feels like there is another way.

We are using postgresql 9.3, and a version change isn't an option at this time.

```
CREATE TABLE t_person (person_id serial, first_name text, last_name text);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (person_id integer, first_name text, last_name text);
INSERT INTO t1 (first_name, last_name) values ('john', 'doe'), ('jane', 'doe');

WITH ins1 AS
(
   INSERT INTO t_person (first_name, last_name)
   SELECT first_name, last_name FROM t1
   RETURNING person_id
)
UPDATE t1 SET person_id=ins1.person_id FROM ins1;
```

The above updates all the rows with the person_id from the final insert (as more or less expected). So is there some way to update only the single row in t1 that was just used to insert into t_person?

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: You also want to avoid duplicates on {firstname, last_name} ?

Comment: Duplicates are allowed. I've thought about using a where clause that checks against everything I've just inserted, but it seemed clunky as well and vulnerable to duplicates.

Comment: If duplicates are allowed, you could just insert (and you wouldn't even need the temp table)